# Flutter: Pass data from Stateful class to another class

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to pass data (`basketCount`) from `Stateful` class (`DashboardState`) to another class doesn't support state (`TestTabBarDelegate`). Both class are in the same file. How can I make it?

I tried `mixins` but `mixins` don't work with a `Stateful` class.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:benyaghlane/widgets/default_aap_bar_row.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:benyaghlane/pages/liste_panier.dart';
import 'package:benyaghlane/pages/produit_sauvegarde.dart';
import 'package:benyaghlane/widgets/grid_categories.dart';
import 'package:benyaghlane/widgets/grid_meilleurs_ventes.dart';
import 'package:benyaghlane/widgets/grid_produits_fards.dart';
import 'package:benyaghlane/widgets/side_drawer.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class TestTabBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  TestTabBarDelegate({this.controller});

  final TabController controller;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 85.0;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 85.0;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: new TabBar(
        controller: controller,
        key: new PageStorageKey<Type>(TabBar),
        labelColor: Colors.black,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12.0),
        indicatorColor: Color(0xff93b800),
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Color(0xff93b800),
            ),
            text: "ACCUEIL",
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.red),
            text: "SAUVEGARDER",
          ),
          Tab(
              text: "PANIER",
              icon: Stack(
                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Color(0xffda9a25)),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 16.0,
                    bottom: 12.0,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xff93b800), shape: BoxShape.circle),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "$basketCount",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant TestTabBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.controller != controller;
  }
}

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DashboardState createState() => new DashboardState();

  int index;
  Dashboard(int index) {
    this.index = index;
  }
}

class DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  TabController _tabController;

  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  int basketCount = 0;

  Future _getBasket() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

    var b = prefs.getString('basket') ?? '';
    if (b != '' && b != '[]') {
      var basket = json.decode(b);
        // this.basketCount = basket.length;
        print(basket.length);
        return basket.length;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    _tabController =
        new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: widget.index);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: new Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 60.0),
          child: new DefaultAppBar()),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
        child: new NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              new SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: false,
                delegate: new TestTabBarDelegate(controller: _tabController),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: new TestHomePageBody(
            tabController: _tabController,
            scrollController: _scrollController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: SideDrawer(),
    );
  }
}

final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];
final List child = map<Widget>(
  imgList,
  (index, i) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.fill, width: 1000.0),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                    Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                'No. $index image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
).toList();

List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
  List<T> result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

class TestHomePageBody extends StatefulWidget {
  TestHomePageBody({this.scrollController, this.tabController});

  final ScrollController scrollController;
  final TabController tabController;

  TestHomePageBodyState createState() => new TestHomePageBodyState();
}

class TestHomePageBodyState extends State<TestHomePageBody> {
  Key _key = new PageStorageKey({});
  bool _innerListIsScrolled = false;

  void _updateScrollPosition() {
    if (!_innerListIsScrolled &&
        widget.scrollController.position.extentAfter == 0.0) {
      setState(() {
        _innerListIsScrolled = true;
      });
    } else if (_innerListIsScrolled &&
        widget.scrollController.position.extentAfter > 0.0) {
      setState(() {
        _innerListIsScrolled = false;
        // Reset scroll positions of the TabBarView pages
        _key = new PageStorageKey({});
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.scrollController.addListener(_updateScrollPosition);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.scrollController.removeListener(_updateScrollPosition);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new TabBarView(
      controller: widget.tabController,
      key: _key,
      children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[ 
                  CarouselSlider(
                    viewportFraction: 1.0,
                    aspectRatio: 2.0,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    enlargeCenterPage: false,
                    items: map<Widget>(
                      imgList,
                      (index, i) {
                        return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(i), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GridCategories(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    CarouselSlider(
                    viewportFraction: 1.0,
                    aspectRatio: 2.0,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    enlargeCenterPage: false,
                    items: map<Widget>(
                      imgList,
                      (index, i) {
                        return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(i), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                      child: Text('Meilleurs ventes',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),
                    ),
                    GridMeilleurVente(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    CarouselSlider(
                    viewportFraction: 1.0,
                    aspectRatio: 2.0,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    enlargeCenterPage: false,
                    items: map<Widget>(
                      imgList,
                      (index, i) {
                        return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(i), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                      child: Text('Produits Phare',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),
                    ),
                    GridProduitsFards(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ProduitSauvegarder(),
        ListPanier(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I expect to show this data inside the widget of the second class `TestTabBarDelegate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your declaration of your `TestTabBarDelegate` you can add a parameter for example:

```dart
TestTabBarDelegate({this.controller, this.basketCount)};

final int basketCount
```

Then reference `basketCount` when you need to display it, for example in your text you can just use `"$basketCount"`.

To get the data there, when you create it you can use:

```dart
return <Widget>[
  new SliverPersistentHeader(
    pinned: false,
    delegate: new TestTabBarDelegate(controller: _tabController, basketCount: basketCount),
  ),
];
```

Comment: Thank you very much @R. Duggan